# Mongod refused to start

Tags: mongodb

I tried starting my mongod  but it only comes on and in less than a second it goes off again i tried  reinstalling it but it started again.

I really don't know how to work my way through this one

The problems result to having a problem with compass   GUI  with this error :

MongoDB not running on the provided host.

Comment: A good first step is checking the contents of the mongodb.log file. If the mongod process is crashing immediately, there should be some errors recorded into this log file which explain why. Could you add this information to your question?

Comment: Have you checked the docs https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/troubleshooting/connection-errors/